# How to filter an array to remove wrong values (like noise)?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, filter, noise

I have a measurement array of 1024 values. But in this array are some values wrong like noise/peaks. The array is normally like sinus so all values should be in a good line.
How can i create a filter to the array to remove these peaks and noise?

I heard something of an algorithm that compares always three values and creates the mean-value of it but I can't find an example of this.

The wrong values are "peaks" which are bigger than the value before so it is perhaps easier if i just compare the value with the value before for a given "Offset"?
But how to do this?

```
public int FilterArray(double[] Values, double Offset, out double[] Results)
{
    int ArrLength = Values.Length;
    Results = new double[ArrLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < ArrLength; i++)
        Values[i] = 0;

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrLength; i++)
        {

          if (Values[i+1] + Offset) > (Values[i]
             {
               // here someting is needed
             }
             else
             {
               // nothing to do if next value is ok
             }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead of an Array. If you need an Array to process your data you can use the ToArray() Method but removing/filtering items from a List is way more easy than resizing Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you heard about **Median Filter** (due to phrase `that compares always three values` phrase). It works good when you have to remove rare peaks.

Example: for data point triplet [3, 100, 7] algorithm finds that **median** (*not mean!*) value of this triplet is 7, and (100) data point is replaced by (7) value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int FilterArray(List<double> Values, double Offset, out double[] Results)
{
    foreach(double value in new List<double>(Values))
    {
        // some logic
        Values.Remove(value);
    }
    return 0; //??
}
```